# Deserilization in java,in google app engine

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, serialization, deserialization

I have a deserialization problem in Java, in Google App Engine.
I want to send a `my_class` object which is serialized.  Although no error is reported on the sending side, the receiving side throws a `ClassNotFoundException` on this code:

```
my_class obj = (my_class) out.readObject();
```

in server code.....

The exception message is showing the client-side `my_Class` name in a path-like form.  I also copied `my_class` file in backend module of appengine, but still I get this error.  Googling points to something like a class loading problem, but I don't understand quite what that is or how to fix it.

my code in android studio
client side

```
URL url = new URL(urln);
s1=s1+" two";
con=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setDoInput(true);
con.setDoOutput(true);
ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(con.getOutputStream()));
oos.reset();
oos.writeObject(objectofserializable_my_class);
oos.flush();
oos.close();
DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream()));
s3=dis.readLine();
```

***which is working fine i am getting `http` response i.e.,`e.getMessage()` exactly `com.package.my_class` but i copied exact my_class.java file in backend module,google appengine but with different package statement in the receiver side...***

server side code on servlet appengine

```
public class ServerSide extends HttpServlet {
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
try {
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(req.getInputStream()));
my_class obj=(my_class)ois.readObject();
String s1=obj.getName();
s=" i got it ";
resp.setContentType("text/plain");
resp.getWriter().println(s);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
resp.getWriter().print(e.getMessage());
} catch(IOException e){
resp.getWriter().print(e.getMessage());
}
}
}
```

Sorry i can't get printstacktrace because it is running in Google App engine......

Comment: Generally speaking, if you want to ask a question here about a Java exception thrown by your program, you should present the actual stack trace including the exact exception message.  Cut & paste it, or capture it to a file.

Comment: Use standard naming conventions.  In particular, class names should start with a capital letter and use CamelCase, not underscores.  This makes it a lot easier for everybody else to read and interpret.

Comment: sure...thanx @John Bollinger

Answer (score 0):

To successfully transfer an object by serialization / deserialization, both parties to the communication must be able to load compatible versions of the class of the object being transferred, and of the classes of any objects accessible via the serialized object (these are transferred, too).  Loading those classes often requires loading other classes, as well.  An object is "accessible via" another object if that other object holds a reference to it in a member variable, directly or indirectly.

The source line you presented refers to class `my_class`, therefore any class whose source contains that line could not itself be loaded without some version of class `my_class` being loaded as well.  Inasmuch as you have attributed the exception to a specific line, I suppose the receiving program actually ran (and therefore first loaded successfully), and that the exception's stack trace identified the line you presented.

In that case, it cannot be that the program throws a `ClassNotFoundException` pertaining to class `my_class`, as it must have not only *found* that class, but *loaded* it already.  I could believe an `InvalidClassException`, which could arise for a couple of different reasons.  If the exception is in fact a `ClassNotFoundException`, however, then it must pertain to a different class.  If `my_class` declares any nested classes, then perhaps one of those is the one that cannot be found (and this is one reason why you should always include the complete exception message and stack trace in your question).  The JVM-format name of such a class would be something like `me/mypackage/my_class$Nested`.

Fix such an exception by putting the needed class file in the receiving program's class path.

Comment: i have exact copy of my_class java file in receiver side also but with different package statement not as same as in sender side @John  please  also tell me how to add class file in CLASSPATH

Answer (score 0):

Ohhhhh god i finally figured it. The package statement of my_class file is different in sender and receiver side so the error `ClassNotFoundException`. somehow after managing same package statement in my_class java file in sender and receiver side.This got clear way out.........
i.e., Exact versions of serializable class should be present in both sender and receiver side...

Comment: If it's in a different package, then it's an *altogether* different class.  Even if everything else about it is the same.